# X-axis in ggplot2 that transitions from linear to log scale

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a histogram in ggplot2 where the x-axis transitions from linear scaling to log2 scaling after a pre-defined point. In other words, I want the x-axis to be of a linear scale up to some threshold, and then after that threshold, use the log2 scale.

So, before the threshold, the x-axis should look like what you would get from simply doing:

```
ggplot(data,aes(x=value)) + geom_histogram()
```

and after the threshold, the x-axis should look like what you would get from doing:

```
ggplot(data,aes(x=value)) + geom_histogram() + scale_x_continuous(trans='log2')
```

The problem is that while I can make those histograms individually (one where everything is on a linear scale, and one where everything is on a log2 scale), I don't know how to get it to transition and have both in one histogram.

Comment: No offense, but this seems like a poor design choice that would be very easy to misinterpret. If there's a real reason to do this comparison, you might try doing them side by side, with one chart filtered for data  below the threshold and the other filtered with data above the threshold

Comment: If you do want to do this (which I would advise against, like camille), the way to do it is to define your own transformation, see `?scales::trans_new`. You can make it as complex and you like. You may want to see `?scales::pseudo_log_trans` for inspiration.

Comment: Thank you to both of you for your feedback and advice! I ended up working with a modification of the pseudo_log_trans.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the commenters that this would be problematic as a single figure. However, it could be informative, if you have one figure showing all data, and then an inset/subplot to show a subset. Here I used `cowplot::plot_grid` to combine two figures, but there are other packages out there for arranging (like `gridExtra`). Do be extremely cautious about how you label the figures.

```
library(ggplot2)
x <- rexp(1000, .05) + rep(c(0, 5), each = 500)

cowplot::plot_grid(
  ggplot(data.frame(x = x[x<5]), aes(x)) + 
    geom_histogram() +
    labs(title = "Subset, x<5, linear-scale"),

  ggplot(data.frame(x), aes(x)) + 
    geom_vline(xintercept = 5, color = "red", size = 2) +
    geom_histogram() +
    scale_x_log10() + 
    labs(title = "All data, log-scale")
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice!